# In Java ME we have tile.setcell(col,row,tileindex) but in andengine how to set the tile?

Tags: android, andengine, tiles

I  am developing android tiled based game using andengine.
in j2me we have tile.setcell(col,row,tileindex) but in andengine how to set the tiles?

Answer (score 0):

Try the TMX Tile map extension:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension

It allow you to use the excellent Time Map Editor http://www.mapeditor.org/
to create your maps, and andengine will parse the XML output from that program.